# What is MOJO in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, mojo, abbreviation

I'm reading about Maven right now and everywhere in a text I see this word (mojo). I approximately understand what it means, but I would not refuse from a good explanation. I tried to google, but found only non-maven explanations.

POJO - ok, but MOJO? Maven Old Java Object?

Comment: :) As I understood - in some sense - it's just wordplay...

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Yes, from http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/index.html:

*What is a Mojo? A mojo is a Maven plain Old Java Object. Each mojo is an executable goal in Maven, and a plugin is a distribution of one or more related mojos.*

In short, a mojo is a maven goal, to extend functionality not already found in maven.

Comment: So is "mojo" just a synonym for "goal" in Maven terminology? Or do they represent different entities that are closely related?

Comment: @waldyrious The "goal" of a "plugin" is a concept. It is implemented using a "mojo".  The "mojo", in its compiled form, resides in the jar corresponding of the plugin. Same thing, different levels of abstraction.

Answer (score 74):

As written [here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-programming-maven.html):

> A Maven Plugin is a Maven artifact which contains a plugin descriptor
>   and one or more Mojos. A Mojo can be thought of as a goal in Maven,
>   and every goal corresponds to a Mojo. The `compiler:compile` goal
>   corresponds to the `CompilerMojo` class in the Maven Compiler Plugin,
>   and the `jar:jar` goal corresponds to the `JarMojo` class in the Maven
>   Jar Plugin. When you write your own plugin, you are simply grouping
>   together a set of related Mojos (or goals) in a single plugin
>   artifact.

A Mojo simply associates with a Maven goal, so we can say a Mojo is much more than just a goal in Maven.

Comment: This is by far the best answer, I feel sorry you don't have more upvotes! The other answers don't give any more information than what is in the documentation already.

Comment: @marcv81 Unfortunately, it's also unoriginal; copy and pasted directly from another source without any attribution.

Comment: Shame. Still useful though.

Answer (score 16):

The [Maven site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugins.html) says Mojo is the combination of "Maven" + "POJO (Plain Old Java Object)". So then, MOJO = Maven Old Java Object.

But another, different answer at [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-programming-maven.html) which I think is from the same group of people that are managing the Maven site suggest Mojo is meant to mean Magical POJO.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the page that "Magical POJO" is suggested; if anything, the page defines what mojo means in classic context, so as to say "but that has nothing to do with this definition."

Comment: Magical POJO is suggested in the last paragraph of the linked document (Maven: The Complete Reference): `Mojo? What is a Mojo? The word mojo is defined as "a magic charm or spell", "an amulet, often in a small flannel bag containing one or more magic items", and "personal magnetism; charm". Maven uses the term Mojo because it is a play on the word Pojo (Plain-old Java Object).`

Comment: @codefan-BK If the Maven site says that the M in Mojo stands for Maven, why would you make the leap to thinking that is suggesting that it is `Magical POGO` instead?  It's already defined.

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling Taking the definition following the link you provided alone your short answer is exhaustive, indeed. But regarding the additional explanation in the second link given by Javateer reveals that the people deciding for the name Mojo thought to play with the word magical as well. So both of you are right, you and Javateer. Both explanations just shed light on two facets of the same subject. I feel no contradiction here, should I?

Comment: @codefan-BK Replacing the word 'Maven' with "Magical' removes the underlying framework... so yes, I'd feel a contradiction :)

Answer (score 4):

- MOJO (**M**aven **O**ld **J**ava **O**bject)  is a goal in Maven.
- In maven, everything is done by plugin, a plugin has one or more related mojos i.e. goals.
- Mojo is single unit of task in maven.

for example : `elicpse:eclipse` the eclipse plugin with eclipse goal is a MOJO